# Program isn't giving me the output I want

Tags: python

I have a program that is reading a file 'flanking seqs' which contains columns of text each meaning something different:

```
1   1   44457990    TAA CTCTCCTAAAGGACC
1   1   44461833    TGA CCAGCCTGAAGGGCT
1   1   148594641   TAA CCACAATAAGCAGCT
1   1   43241066    TGA ACTCACTGAGAGTGG
1   1   43240880    TAG CTTCTCTAGGAATGG ...
```

First col: chromosome number, second col: DNA strand, third col: position of stop codon in DNA, fourth col: stop codon, fifth col: 6 bases upstream and downstream surrounding the stop codon, i.e. the flanking sequence of each stop codon.

Now, my program is supposed to read this file and extract the 3 bases before and after each stop codon from the flanking sequence column and write to a file containing two columns: the stop codon and then the flanking sequence.  The file should contain flanking sequences of all three stop codons TAA, TAG and TGA, however when I run the program, it only gives me the flanking sequences for TGA stop codons, but not for the rest of them.

Here is an example of what the outfile looks like:

```
TGA GGGCTT  1
TGA GAACGT  2
TGA CTTCTT  17
TGA CACCCT  15
TGA GAACGG  1
TGA GAACGC  3
```

I can't see where I am going wrong but I'm not very experienced so I'm sure I am missing something simple.  I'd appreciate any help in spotting my errors!  Here is the code:

```
bases = ['A','T','C','G']
sequenceCount = {}
for x1 in bases:
    for x2 in bases:
        for x3 in bases:
            for x4 in bases:
                for x5 in bases:
                    for x6 in bases:
                        sequenceCount[x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6] = 0 
infile = open('flanking seqs.txt','rU')
outfile = open('context resultsNEW.txt','w')

for line in infile:
    parts = line.split('\t') 
    chromosome = parts[0] 
    position = int(parts[2])
    stopcodon = parts[3]
    flankseq = parts[4].strip()
    flankseq = flankseq[3:6]+flankseq[9:12]
    if flankseq in sequenceCount:  
        sequenceCount[flankseq] += 1    
for s in sequenceCount:   
    outfile.write(stopcodon+'\t'+s+'\t'+str(sequenceCount[s])+'\n')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `outfile.write` takes place outside of the `for line in infile` loop, so the value of `stopcodon` is always whatever value it had in the final line of your input text file.

If you're trying to correlate sequence counts against both stop codons and flank sequences, you'll need to use both variables as a key. If you don't know all stop codons ahead of time, you won't be able to initialize `sequenceCount`'s values to 0 using your "multiple nested for loops" approach, so you should probably use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
sequenceCount = defaultdict(int)

infile = open('flanking seqs.txt','rU')
outfile = open('context resultsNEW.txt','w')

for line in infile:
    parts = line.split('\t') 
    chromosome = parts[0] 
    position = int(parts[2])
    stopcodon = parts[3]
    flankseq = parts[4].strip()
    flankseq = flankseq[3:6]+flankseq[9:12]
    sequenceCount[flankseq, stopcodon] += 1
for key, value in sequenceCount.iteritems():
    flankseq, stopcodon = key
    outfile.write(stopcodon+'\t'+s+'\t'+str(sequenceCount[s])+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you produce your output, you print the last `stopcodon` that was read from the file with every line, regardless of what values for `stopcodon` were used in the previous loop.  Perhaps your `sequenceCount` dictionary needs to be indexed by a combination of `stopcodon` and `flankseq`?